# how to create a list sequence in python containing all possible pairs an equal number of times?

Tags: python, list, function, sequence

Given the letters `x,y` is there a way to write a python function that returns a list sequence containing all possible pairs (`[x,x], [x,y], [y,x], [y,y]`) an equal number of times?

for example can I write a function that takes the input (eg `[x,y]`) and the number of times each possible pair should appear (eg `2`), and then returns, for example, the list sequence:
`[x x x y y x y y x]` ?

Preferably I would like the function to generate a "random" sequence so it could also return:

```
[y x y y x x x y y]
```

In both cases `[x,x] [x,y] [y,x]` and `[y,y]` appear exactly twice.

Ideally, I would like to find a solution that also worked with for example 4 letters `[x,y,z,w]`.

Comment: Do you have any preference for how many times the pairs appear? We can do this with each ordered pair appearing exactly once, and by cycling through the list repeatedly, we can have any desired number of repetitions of the pairs.

Comment: Would this work: `(xxyyzz) * n + x`?

Comment: It looks like people are interpreting your question in very different ways. Could you edit your question to clarify exactly what you're asking?

Comment: @user2357112: Yes, I would like to control the number of times pairs appear. Also, the program should generate a different sequence of pairs when I run it, although it may have a limit of sequences it can generate. I'll try to make the question clearer.

Comment: @HappyPy so, to clarify, your problem is going from an alphabet (x, y, z, etc.) to a list sequence [x, y, y, z, x, ...] containing all possible permutations? What do you mean by "generate a different sequence of pairs when I run it" and "control number of times pairs appear"?

Comment: @Erin Veasey: I updated my question. I hope it's a bit clearer now.

Comment: @user2357112: I updated my question. I hope it's a bit clearer now.

Comment: What you're looking for is a random or random-ish Eulerian tour on the directed multigraph with all your desired pairs as edges. This is quite doable, with a level of difficulty corresponding to how much you care about all valid outputs being possible or equally likely. If you don't care much, there are simple, generalizable patterns you could hardcode, and you could shuffle the list of letters before applying the pattern.

Comment: @user2357112: Thanks for your comment. The first option is interesting but unfortunately I'm not familiar with the Eulerian tour method. Is there a module in python I could import that could help me implement this? I would also be happy with the second option. The problem is that manually generating even just one pattern using 4 letters with each pair appearing 30 times is probably not feasible. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your edits, the following should conduct the tour to which you were referring.

```
import random
import itertools

def generate_sequence(alphabet, num_repeats):

    # generate the permutations of the list of size 2
    # repeated `num_repeats` times
    perms = [(letter1, letter2) for letter1, letter2 in itertools.product(alphabet, alphabet) for i in xrange(num_repeats)]

    # save the original length of `perm` for later
    perm_len = len(perms)

    # randomly choose a starting point and add it to our result
    curr_s, curr_e = random.choice(perms)
    result = [curr_s, curr_e]

    # remove the starting point from the list... on to the next one
    perms.remove((curr_s, curr_e))

    # while we still have pairs in `perms`...
    while len(perms):

        # get all possible next pairs if the end of the current pair
        # equals the beginning of the next pair
        next_vals = [(s,e) for s,e in perms if s == curr_e]

        # if there aren't anymore, we may have exhausted the pairs that
        # start with `curr_e`, in which case choose a new random pair
        if len(next_vals) != 0:
            next_s, next_e = random.choice(next_vals)
        else:
            next_s, next_e = random.choice(perms)

        # remove the next pair from `perm` and append it to the `result`
        perms.remove((next_s, next_e))
        result.append(next_e)

        # set the current pair to the next pair and continue iterating...
        curr_s, curr_e = next_s, next_e

    return result

alphabet = ('x', 'y', 'z')
num_repeats = 2
print generate_sequence(alphabet, num_repeats)
```

This outputs

```
['z', 'z', 'z', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'y', 'y', 'z', 'y', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'z', 'x', 
 'z', 'y', 'x']
```

Comment: I think you misinterpreted the question. We want to produce `x, y, y, z, x ...` given `x, y, z`.

Comment: @user2357112 If I follow your comment, given the pairs `[['x', 'z'], ...]`, you want to produce the sequence ['x', 'z', ...]?

Comment: We're not given pairs. We're given a set of letters, and we want to produce a list where adjacent elements of the list form every possible ordered pair an equal number of times.

Comment: @user2357112 -- Ok, so I believe I have done just that. I'm not following where I've misinterpreted OPs problem.

Comment: How do you think your code does anything like what I've described? For one thing, your code's input is what I'm saying should be the output.

Comment: @user2357112 -- The confusion lies in this statement: "for example the list sequence [x y y z x z z y x x z x y y z z y x x] contains the pairs [x,y], [y,y], [y,z], [z,x], [x,z], [z,z], etc, exactly twice." If the list [x, y, y, ...] is the input, then my solution is valid. If by "write a python function that returns a list sequence containing all possible pairs an equal number of times?", OP meant we simply get an alphabet and are to generate the list [x y y ... ] list, then yes, your assessment is correct and my solution is incorrect.

Comment: @Michael Recachinas: Thank you for your answer. I updated my question. I hope it's clearer.

Comment: @HappyPy -- Not a problem -- updating.

Comment: You seem to have neglected to consider the fact that pairs overlap. For example, if you generate `['x', 'y', 'z', 'x', ...]`, the `'y', 'z'` pair counts as well as the `'x', 'y'` and `'z', 'x'` pairs.

Comment: @Michael Recachinas: Thanks for your help. I noticed that generate_sequence sometimes produces more combinations of a pair than other pairs, because as you say in a comment, pairs starting with curr_e may have been exhausted. I guess I can just run the function continuously until it finds the best solution. Is there a way to change the else clause to something like "else: generate_sequence(alphabet, num_repeats)" in order to reset the function and start anew?

Comment: @HappyPy -- Certainly. You could definitely have something like `else: return generate_sequence(alphabet, num_repeats)`, but the issue will be the case where you continue to randomly choose a path that runs out of options and recurse above the maximum stack depth. Therefore, the nondeterminism here may not be exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @Michael Recachinas: It works great! Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

With this you can take the most common pairs:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> dict(Counter(zip(a, a[1:])).most_common())
{('z', 'z'): 2, ('z', 'y'): 2, ('x', 'y'): 2, ('z', 'x'): 2, ('y', 'y'): 2, ('x', 'x'): 2, ('y', 'x'): 2, ('x', 'z'): 2, ('y', 'z'): 2}
```

If you care about the pairs only:

```
>>> [t[0] for t in Counter(zip(a, a[1:])).most_common()]
[('z', 'z'), ('z', 'y'), ('x', 'y'), ('z', 'x'), ('x', 'x'), ('y', 'x'), ('x', 'z'), ('y', 'y'), ('y', 'z')]
```

If you only care which pairs appear 2 times:

```
>>> [pair for pair, count in Counter(zip(a, a[1:])).items() if count == 2]
[('z', 'z'), ('z', 'y'), ('x', 'y'), ('z', 'x'), ('x', 'x'), ('y', 'x'), ('x', 'z'), ('y', 'y'), ('y', 'z')]
```